# Vuetifys adding a solo textfield in a toolbar fails

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

Am trying to add a solo textfield in a toolbar but this fails

so i have

```
 <v-toolbar dense flat dark color="primary">
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
        <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-text-field

                light
                solo
                placeholder="Search an item here"
        ></v-text-field>

        <v-spacer></v-spacer>

        <v-divider inset
                   vertical
        ></v-divider>

        <v-btn text class="text-none">
            Action Menu
        </v-btn>

    </v-toolbar>
```

The above produces
[image]

which i would like centered vertically on the toolbar (like the title)

I have also tried adding a margin to the solo text field but still it doesnt center it on the toolbar.

I have made a [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/geowan/pen/vYBLvWM) for the above isse

What do i need to add to it to make it center

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have `hide-details` on your `v-text-field` and also height of `dense`-ed toolbar is to small for `v-text-field` inside (except you use css to customize `v-text-field` height).

Here is simple example:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container style="margin-top:40px">

        <v-toolbar flat dark color="primary">
            <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
            <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
            <v-text-field hide-details solo single-line class="ml-5" light></v-text-field>

            <v-spacer></v-spacer>

            <v-divider inset
                       vertical
            ></v-divider>

            <v-btn text class="text-none">
                Action Menu
            </v-btn>

        </v-toolbar>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```